How can I disable direct mapping feature gate on local test validator?
I need to test some code that looks like it may work differently on mainnet, which currently does not have the feature gate active.

In order to deactivate a feature on a solana-test-validator, you would have to use --deactivate-feature on startup.
For direct mapping, this would be:
solana-test-validator --deactivate-feature EenyoWx9UMXYKpR8mW5Jmfmy2fRjzUtM7NduYMY8bx33

